# Adding multiple headers through a wrapper around Kendo Angular Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to add a multi header in Kendo angular grid as displayed here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/headers/

We have a wrapper around the Kendo Angular Grid and a common markup. Most of the places the wrapper is used will not be needing the multiple headers.

The current markup in the wrapper for columns is like this: (simplified)

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let col of dataOptions.columns; trackBy: trackByColumnField">
   <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column>
        {{ column.title }}
   </ng-template>
```

If we need to add multi header:

**Option 1:**
Add separate htmls to add top header where needed

```
<ng-container *ngIf='dataOptions.columnGroups && dataOptions.columnGroups.length > 0'>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let obj  of dataOptions.columns | groupBy: '_groupKey'; trackBy: trackByColumnField">
        <kendo-grid-column-group [title]="obj.key | translate">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of obj.value; trackBy: trackByColumnField">
                   // Html for kendo-grid-column goes here 
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </kendo-grid-column-group>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container> 

<ng-container *ngIf="!dataOptions.columnGroups">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of dataOptions.columns; trackBy: trackByColumnField">
                   // Html for kendo-grid-column goes here 
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**Option 2**: Add a top header for all the grids and hide with css where needed

**Option 3**: Abstract out kendo-grid-column html using ngTemplateOutlet
Not supported as mentioned in: https://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-multi-column-headers

Option 1 and Option 2 are not very attractive and Option 3 is not possible.

Is there any other way this can be achieved?